# Decorator Pattern, decorating subclasses that contain different methods

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, decorator

Suppose I have an `Animal` abstract class and three classes `Dog`,`Cat`, and `Bear` that extend the `Animal` class. `Animal` class has abstract method `getDescription`. `Dog` class has a method `getNumberOfHomeworksEaten`, but `Cat` and `Bear` do not. Suppose I have a decorators `YellowStripes`, `BlueStripes`, `GreenStripes` that all extend the `Animal` class and decorates the `getDescription` method. If I decorate `Dog` , `Cat`, and `Bear` with the decorators:

```
Animal dog = new Dog();
dog = YellowStripes(dog);
dog = BlueStripes(dog);
dog = GreenStripes(dog);

Cat cat = new Cat();
//decorate cat

Bear bear = new Bear();
//decorate bear
```

How can I access the `getNumberOfHomeworksEaten` method for `dog`? It wouldn't make sense to have `getNumberOfHomeworksEaten` in each decorator since `Cat` and `Bear` do not have that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast `dog` to `Dog` you will be able to use this method.

```
Animal animal = new Dog();
animal = YellowStripes(animal);
animal = BlueStripes(animal);
animal = GreenStripes(animal);

Dog dog = (Dog) animal;
dog.getNumberOfHomeworksEaten();
```

Comment: Side note: In your example all decorators would have to extend `Dog`, otherwise you end up in a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: I do not understand why this answer was accepted since, as @home commented, this approach completely undermines the whole point of decorators. With this "solution" one should create a decorator class for every subclass.